# Remotely accessing GPIO

Tags: python, ajax, raspberry-pi

I have a Raspberry pi 3. and installed web server. I have a file http1.py that listens to port 432 and with variable "a" that passes from URL, it will turn lights on and off through GPIO: "http://192.168.0.5:432/turn?a=1" 
I also opened the  ip forwarding on my router under port 80 and it works.
On my raspberry pi server I have  index.html file that uses Ajax to access the http://192.168.0.5:432/turn?a=1:

```
function ras(str) {
    var url = "HTTP://192.168.0.17:432/turn?a="+str;
    xmlHttp = GetXmlHttpObject(stateChanged);
    xmlHttp.open("GET", url, true);
    xmlHttp.send(null); .....
}

function stateChanged() {
    if (xmlHttp.readyState == 4 || xmlHttp.readyState == "complete") {
        Blah, blah ...
```

now, with-in the network, it works fine (turn GPIO on and off) but with external ipaddress 75.129.-.-:80, I see the index.html  BUT when I access the link which activate the Ajax, nothing happens.

What am I doing wrong? Or, is there any better way to access the GPIO from out of my network?

Comment: Where is your python script?

Comment: it is under /var/www/html . same directory as index.html and when I run the http1.py from command from this location, it works fine

Comment: You javascript code is run in your browser. It has no access to serve's local network, unless your browser is on server's local network itself.

Comment: yes, That make sense.  is there any recommendation on how to access the raspberry from outside of network?

Comment: Can I edit the Ajax with external ip address: var url = "HTTP://75.129.-.-:432/turn?a="+str;  ??

Answer (score 0):

Well, I found the best/effective way to control GPIO on you Raspberry Pi is through  wiringpi.  You must have PHP and wiring Pi installed and configured. once it is done you can use PHP in combination with Ajax to create a cool, one page GUI interface for GPIO which can be accessed from anywhere out side of your network.  take necessary steps to hack proof the page